# There's a NaN error in one of the tables on my PHP Laravel Script, What could be the problem?

Tags: php, laravel, nan

This is an Inventory Management System with POS, HRM, and Accounting site.
The code was working perfectly, But suddenly its began to display some errors, I edited and corrected them only to be stocked at NaN error in my add sales table.

NaN instead of the actual number.

[image: issue]

Tried to debug, But I can't find the source of problem.

Comment: if you are not able to share any code, it is totally impossible for us to help you... is that table generated by an external package? is that table generated by custom code you have access to? since when did it start failing? you need to share more debugging details as we cannot do anything without more info, and share all this data (code) as plain text, not images please

Comment: Check the developer console of the browser. If you get the data with ajax, watch the Network tab and see what the values are for those particular fields. Are they supposed to be calculations? If so, what are the actual values it's calculating -- not the variables, but the values.

Comment: We can't fix pictures of your app (any more than a mechanic can fix a picture of a car). Frankly that ought to be self-evident, yet here we are. Take a look at [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue